# Percorrer array e tirar elementos vazios

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse array:

```
{data: Array(5)}
data: Array(5)
0: {tag: " "}
1: {tag: "a"}
2: {tag: "b"}
3: {tag: "c"}
4: {tag: "  "}
length: 5
```

como faço para percorrer o array e tirar os elementos vazios?

ex:

```
{data: Array(5)}
    data: Array(5)
    1: {tag: "a"}
    2: {tag: "b"}
    3: {tag: "c"}
    length: 5
```

"Vazio" seria elementos em brancos.

Comment: Pode definir para nós o que você considera "vazio" nesse contexto? Um espaço em branco comumente **não é** considerado como vazio. Quais são os casos que você considerará vazio? Espaços? Quebras de linhas? Tabulações? Caracteres não visíveis? etc.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss espaços/em branco.

Comment: Porque os indices não desceram no resultado ? Não deveriam ser 0,1 e 2 ? O mesmo em relação ao `length`, porque é 5 e não 3 ?

Comment: @Isac eu só apaguei as linhas para mostrar como gostaria que ficasse como exemplo, é o mesmo de cima.

Comment: E os outros caracteres, quebra de linha, tabulação, etc, serão considerados "vazios" também? Exemplo: `{tag: '\t\r\n'}`

Answer (score 5):

Pode utilizar o [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) que lhe devolve um array filtrado de acordo com o critério que quiser. No caso basta que o critério seja aplicado com o [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) para cortar os espaços em branco e que garanta pelo menos um caretere:

```js
const arr = [{tag:" "}, {tag:"a"}, {tag:"b"}, {tag:"c"}, {tag:"  "}];

const filtrado = arr.filter(x => x.tag.trim().length > 0);
console.log(filtrado);
```

Claro que também pode fazer um laço/ciclo normal com um `for` por exemplo e ir testando com um `if` e adicionando a um novo array se não for vazio, mas acaba por representar a mesma lógica que o `filter` já segue.

Assim como comentado pelo @fernandosavio no `filter` interessa devolver verdadeiro para manter o elemento ou falso para excluir. Como uma `string` vazia é um [*falsy value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), e uma `string` com conteúdo é um [*truthy value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) dá para usar a `string` que sai do `trim` diretamente:

```
const filtrado = arr.filter(x => x.tag.trim());
```

Comment: +1 Só para constar, o `.length > 0` é desnecessário na função do `filter` pois uma string vazia, quando convertida para `boolean`, é `false`. Poderia ser `x => x.tag.trim()` sem problema.

Comment: @fernandosavio Agradeço o comentário. Sim de facto é algo que se costuma utilizar neste tipo de casos que acabei por nem mencionar, mas que é relevante.